# How to write fixtures in python language and not serialized for django?

Tags: django, fixtures

I have a python file that creates objects with this method Category.objects.create. But I don't know how to run that fixture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixtures are serialized. Python code that populates the database is not a fixture.

If you want to populate the database with python code after the it has been created, I suggest you attach your creation function to the [`post_syncdb`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-syncdb) signal. Note that the signal is sent per application.

In your callback function, you can check the `created_signals` parameter, to see which models were created, and check whether you need to create the objects.

As a reference, have a look at the contrib apps that use the `post_syncdb` signal, for example  [`django.contrib.sites.manage`](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/sites/management.py), which creates the default site instance only once.

Comment: but the post_syncdb will not add over and over again? I only need to be added once...

Comment: Yes, You need to add checks in your callback to prevent the models being created multiple times. I've updated my answer with a link to an example.